# Can I declare a variable without $ in PHP

Tags: php, variables, zend-certification

I saw this code in a PHP book (PHP architect, ZEND PHP 5 Certification guide page 141)

```
class foo{
  public $bar;
  protected $baz;
  private $bas;

  public var1="Test"; //String
  public var2=1.23; //Numericvalue
  public var3=array(1,2,3);
}
```

and it says

> Properties are declared in PHP using one of the PPP operators, followed by their
>   name:
>
> Note that, like a normal variable, a class property can be initialized while it is being
>   declared. However, the initialization is limited to assigning values (but not by
>   evaluating expressions). You can’t,for example,initialize a variable by calling a function—that’s something you can only do within one of the class’ methods (typically,
>   the constructor).

I can not understand how `var1, var2, var3` are declared. Isn't it illegal?

Comment: Obviously an error. My copy has the same glitch, even though it seems to be  a different edition (I've this listing on page 122)

Comment: Are you sure you copy everything correctly?

Comment: It's a Typo.  You can have a constant that you set like that, and without a '$'. They are by convention usually in UPPER_CASE. "const VAR1 = 'test';"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sample code is (almost) valid (it's just missing a few $ signs.)

```
class foo
{
    // these will default to null
    public $bar;
    protected $baz;
    private $bas;

    // perfectly valid initializer to "string" value
    public $var1 = "Test"; //String

    // perfectly valid initializer to "float" value
    public $var2 = 1.23;    //Numericvalue

    // perfectly valid initializer to "array" value
    // (array() is a language construct/literal, not a function)
    public $var3 = array(1,2,3);
}
```

So, the book your code comes from is definitely in error.

Comment: actually this is not written by me , i took it from  http://www.4shared.com/document/ufVfSY1Q/PHP_Architect_Zend_PHP_5_Certi.html    page 141

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya: yes I got that, but I only after fixing the glaring omission in the code. ;)

Comment: i though may be there a way in PHP to declare a variable with out $ sign :(

Comment: you could use constants, but they are not variable. see http://php.net/constant and http://php.net/define (also note that i'm not recommending this, just providing reference.)

Answer (score 3):

No, this is an error. Defining:

```
public var1="Test"; //String
```

Will give you:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE
```

For details, see http://codepad.org/meMrSmfA.

Answer (score 2):

Variables in PHP are ["represented by a dollar sign followed by the name of the variable"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php). Although dollarless variables [have been requested](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54325), I doubt whether they we ever see them enabled.

Point in short: your code is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

In php variable are auto casting.whatever you want keep in a variable no need to declare it type .
But one mandatory thing is that when you going to declare a Variable in php you must have to use "$"
which one you missed .Book declaration is

```
  public var1="Test"; //String
  public var2=1.23; //Numericvalue
  public var3=array(1,2,3);
```

its a wrong declaration 
Right is

```
public $var1="Test"; //String
public $var2=1.23; //Numericvalue
public $var3=array(1,2,3);
```

that's other wise every thing are fine .
Thank you